# How to add a namespace and another namespace with a prefix in XML inside the doc

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, attributes

My Goal is create an `XML node` that has two `attributes` - one is a `namespace` and another is a `prefix` of that `namespace`, as shown below:

[image]

So far I have tried 3 options:

**Option 1**: Hardcoding it, does not work.

```
        XElement paymentmethodType = XElement.Parse("<PaymentMethod xmlns:xsi=\"w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"CreditTransferType\"/>");
```

I only get this:

```
 <PaymentMethod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="CreditTransferType">
```

**Option 2** : Using my structure with XmlAttributes and XMlNodes:

```
    XmlAttribute paymentmethodNamespace = CreateAttribute(paymentMethod, "xmlns:xsi", "http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    XmlAttribute paymentmethodType = CreateAttribute(paymentMethod, "xsi:type", "CreditTransferType");

    public XmlAttribute CreateAttribute(XmlNode parentNode, string attributeName, string attributeValue)
    {
        var attribute = parentNode.OwnerDocument.CreateAttribute(attributeName);
        attribute.Value = attributeValue;
        parentNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
        // parentNode.AppendChild(node);
        return attribute;
    }
```

I again get this:

```
 <PaymentMethod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="CreditTransferType">
```

**Option 3** : XElement and XAttributes:

```
        XElement paymentMethod = new XElement("PaymentMethod",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi:type", "CreditTransferType"));
```

But i get an `Exception` that ":" is not a valid symbol. Also it is a problem because I use `XMlDocument` and it only works with `XMlNode` and `XMlAttribute`. It does not work with `XAttribute`.

Now I have over 400 lines of codes and I just want to set this namespace and I am done with the doc. Is there an easy way of doing it?

Comment: Your Option 1 works.  What is the issue?

Comment: hi jdweng. it does not get xsi:type it just gets type therefore the web service rejects the doc based on that.

Comment: I put a break point after the code and then hovered over paymentmethodType and selected the arrow and view XML and it matches the input.  Not sure how you are viewing.

Comment: Yeah the code shows it fine. But when you saved it to an XML it does not in the xml itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `Option 1` and `Option 2` but for `Option 3` - What you have to do is Get the `namespace` first, then use the `namespace` to assign `type`. Because that namespace is `xmlns:xsi` , you assign it type it will automatically match to `xsi:type`. In short here is the code:

```
            XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");


              new XElement("PaymentMethod",


                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),

                  new XAttribute(ns + "type", "CreditTransferType"));
```

Comment: I tested that and it does the job. The question is how to I add this to a node in my XML?

Answer (score 1):

The following works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             string xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><root></root>";
             XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlHeader);
             XElement root = doc.Root;

             XElement paymentmethodType = XElement.Parse("<PaymentMethod xmlns:xsi=\"w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"CreditTransferType\"/>");
             root.Add(paymentmethodType);

             doc.Save(FILENAME);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I used option 3 as dim suggested.

What I did so I do not have to rewrite the whole lot was to create a second document that loads the XML.

Then the first doc imports the node from the second doc and appends it to the root element and it works fine.

```
            XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();


            XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");


             XElement paymentMethodEl =  new XElement("PaymentMethod",


                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),

                  new XAttribute(ns + "type", "CreditTransferType"));

            doc2.LoadXml(paymentMethodEl.ToString());

            XmlWriter writer2 = XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(Settings.Default.InvoiceXmlFolder, "doc2.xml"), settings);
            doc2.Save(writer2);
            XmlNode paymentMethod = doc.ImportNode(doc2.FirstChild, true);
            rootNode.AppendChild(paymentMethod);
```